# Babel does compile no more with Turkish language

Tags: babel, turkish

What is wrong or missing in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[turkish,italian]{babel}
\babelfont[italian]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{EB Garamond}
\babelfont[turkish]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{italian}

Quel ramo del lago di Como

\end{document}
```

for:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\let 
l.7 \begin{document}
```

Thank you

ms

Comment: It does compile without errors for me on LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 and XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)

Comment: I can confirm the problem. This looks like a `babel` bug...

Comment: The example compiles fine on my MikTeX system, which currently lags behind TeX live a bit. I suspect the `expl3` update might have caused this, but have no evidence to back that up.

Comment: I've `Package: babel 2020/02/03 3.39 The Babel package` (Texlive 2019 always udated). It seems to me too a bug of latest release

Comment: @user41063 This is a bad interaction between `babel` and the new `expl3` case-changing code. `babel` relies on some implementation details of `\Make(Upper|Lower)case`, and `expl3` didn't expect that and it broke. An update should be out in a couple days, to fix this issue. Meanwhile you can add the `nocase` option to `babel` to have your document compile again.

Comment: yes, with `nocase` it works! thank you

Comment: @user41063 Great! Just so that you know, the fix was just sent to CTAN, so you should have an update in two days or so, then you can remove `nocase`.

Comment: As an aside, if you load two languages and they share the font, just say `\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{EB Garamond}` (TeX ligatures are activated by default).

Comment: yes, from some days all works fine. thank you!